# "match" VS "match with"

Tags: prepositions

> 1. It was a hard time for private enterprises to expand business as we relied mostly on imports of core parts that not always **match** our machinery.
> 2. It was a hard time for private enterprises to expand business as we relied mostly on imports of core parts that not always **match with** our machinery.
> 3. It was a hard time for private enterprises to expand business as we relied mostly on imports of core parts that not always ***fit with*** our machinery.
> 4. It was a hard time for private enterprises to expand business as we relied mostly on imports of core parts that not always ***fit*** our machinery.

Among the above four lines, which one is the most suitable?

Comment: If it can be an option that is not out of the four you gave us, "compatible with" is a better fit.

Comment: Except for missing "do" any of those sentences could be correct but mean different things.  The first two imply the parts work but aren't ideal.  The second two imply the parts *don't work*.  Which situation are you trying to describe?

Comment: correction: that did not always match our machinery

Comment: Please note: in technical English, we tend to use: right parts and wrong parts and do not talk about matching and fitting in that sense. These are the wrong parts for our machines.

Answer (score 1):

"Fit" is the better word in this context to describe whether or not a part is physically compatible with a machine.

This sentence needs the auxiliary verb `do` to "help" the full verb `fit`.  Since you are using past tense, the word `did` is needed.

For example:

**It was a hard time for private enterprises to expand business as we relied mostly on imports of core parts that *did* not always *fit* our machinery.**

You can break this part of the sentence apart into a smaller sentence to help you remember:

✓ Parts always fit. (correct)

X Parts not always fit. (incorrect)

✓ Parts do not always fit. (correct)

Comment: A general statement would not be private enterprises. General statements would use either **private enterprise or businesses**